# How to receive a response from multiple instances of the same telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, .net-4.8

I have 2 instances of the same software that are using the same bot token ( therefore are the same Telegram bot ), so **1 bot but more instances that runs it**.

I do so because i want to monitor various windows services on multiple machines, and i do not want to create a bot for each one so i've installed the same bot on each machine.

**The problem is that i do not have the certainty that i will receive the response from each instance every time i make a request, sometime i receive both responses, sometime i receive only one**;

To me seems like my request (my message in the chat [bot commands] ) arrives first to an instance than the other (of course), and somehow my request is removed from the chat and not seen from every instance.

As you can see from the code below i am using various async methods for handling chat events

```
        Bot = new TelegramBotClient(token);
        Bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnMessageEdited += BotOnMessageReceived;
        Bot.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallbackQueryReceived;
        Bot.StartReceiving();
```

this is where the user requests arrive

```
async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEvent)
    {
        if (messageEvent.Message.Text != null && 
            chatIDs.Contains(messageEvent.Message.Chat.Id))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received a text message in chat 
            {messageEvent.Message.Chat.Id}.");

            int delay = new Random().Next(3, 4) * 1000;

            Thread.Sleep(delay);

            if (messageEvent.Message.Text.Equals(GetStatusMessage))
            {
                await getSevicesStatus(messageEvent.Message.Chat.Id);
            }
            else if (messageEvent.Message.Text.Equals(SetStatusMessage))
            {
                await setSevicesStatus(messageEvent.Message.Chat.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see from the code i tried forcing a random delay and found out that it alters the bot behavior, making both instances write their corresponding responses (sometimes)

So my question is :
**Which is the correct way to handle multiple instances of the same bot like in this situation, so that every instance can post their response to my requests ?**

```
Assembly Telegram.Bot, Version=15.7.1.0
```